# Animation chart js (line), animate chart drawing line by line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there a way to extend the current chart.js so that the animation drawing doesn't animate the whole chart, but drawing the chart line by line with animation (ease) ?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Nevermind.I've implement it by extending chart.js and override draw() function so that  I can animate the line from one dot/point to another until the last dot / point.

Comment: You might want to post the code in this answer to make this more useful. Cheers!

Comment: Could you please post the code here? I am stuck on the same issue.

Comment: could you please post the code here , thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `onAnimationComplete` callback to change the data and call `update()`

```
            ...
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }
    ]
};

var data2 = [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90];

var done = false;
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    animationEasing: 'linear',
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        if (!done) {
            myLineChart.datasets[1].points.forEach(function (point, i) {
                point.value = data2[i];
            });
            myLineChart.update();
            done = true;
        }
    }
});
```

It works better with `linear` easing (otherwise it seems like 2 distinct animations), but if you wanted to, you could write your own easing function to do `easeOutQuart` in 2 blocks.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rnyekq1y/