# ChartJS, add new dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm wondering how to display my 3 curves as follow : firstly the first one, after 5000 interval, add the second, and after 5000 again, add the third dataset.

The folowing code update one of the points in the second dataset, but what I want is to add a full dataset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="updating-chart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
 <script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
      labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
      datasets: [

          {    //first dataset
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: [69.23077, 78.18182, 66.66667, 65.45455, 38.18182, 40.35088, 45.61404, 36.53846, 43.28358, 54.54545, 31.25000, 44.73684]
          }
          ,
           {  // Second dataset
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: [25.00000, 12.72727, 22.22222, 18.18182, 54.54545, 40.35088, 45.61404, 42.30769, 31.34328, 21.81818, 34.37500, 36.84211]
          },
          {   // third dataset
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: [1.923077, 3.636364, 4.444444, 5.454545, 0.000000, 5.263158, 3.508772, 9.615385, 16.417910, 18.181818, 34.375000, 15.789474]
          }


      ]
    };

// Reduce the animation steps for demo clarity.
var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(startingData, {animationSteps: 15});


setInterval(function(){

  // Update one of the points in the second dataset
  myLiveChart.datasets[1].points[1].value =  Math.random();


  myLiveChart.update();
}, 5000);




 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Must it be done with ChartJS?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if there's any other nice way to do this, i'm interested :)

Comment: Actually I spotted this, maybe it helps? http://jsbin.com/horoze/edit?html,output
Or maybe I am not sure what you want to achieve visually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think that it do not add sequentially the curve. Visually what I want is to display only the red curve, after 5 seconds to add the green curve, and after 7 seconds add the blue curve. I'm looking for a kind of fonction that will allow me to add dataset in each setinterval

Comment: Try highcharts, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-plot-bands/ and here is the web page http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set every array except the first one to blank. Then use `onAnimationComplete` to progressively load them back.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010562/360067

```
...

var dataArrays = [];
for (var i = 1; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
    dataArrays.push(data.datasets[i].data);
    data.datasets[i].data = data.datasets[i].data.map(function() {
        return 0
    });
}    

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
  animationEasing: 'linear',
  onAnimationComplete: function () {
    if (dataArrays.length !== 0) {
      var index = myLineChart.datasets.length - dataArrays.length;
      myLineChart.datasets[index].points.forEach(function (point, i) {
        point.value = dataArrays[0][i];
      });
      myLineChart.update();
      dataArrays.shift();
    }
  }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ngf79suk/

Comment: Fantastic :) thank you ! Is there a way in this code to specify nb second before displaying the next curve ?

Comment: You can use `animationSteps` to control the speed of animation - see http://jsfiddle.net/fb1jozrp/. Or if you want to do it in steps, turn off the animation and use setInterval - see http://jsfiddle.net/v831rd4g/

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot !